# How to get ROS xml param from launch file using Python

Tags: python, xml, ros, ar.drone

I have a launch file which extension is xml, and I would like to get the value of a parameter. This launch file is called ardrone.launch

```
<!-- This is a sample lanuch file, please change it based on your needs -->
<launch>
    <node name="ardrone_driver" pkg="ardrone_autonomy" type="ardrone_driver" output="screen" clear_params="true">
        <param name="outdoor" value="1" />
        <param name="flight_without_shell" value="1" />
        <param name="max_bitrate" value="4000" />
        <param name="bitrate" value="4000" />
        <param name="navdata_demo" value="0" />
        <param name="altitude_max" value="10000" />
        <param name="altitude_min" value="50" />
        <param name="euler_angle_max" value="0.35" />
        <param name="control_vz_max" value="2000" />
        <param name="control_yaw" value="1.75" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

For example, I would like to get the value from altitude_max, altitude_min, and the others using python. I have to add that this file is inside a directory called launch and the file where I am calling it is at a directory called scripts, and scripts and launch are both in the same directory.

Comment: After reading your question again, I am not 100% sure, what you are doing. Are you calling the launch-file to start the script (this is what I assume in my answer) or do you only want to read the parameters from the launch-file without actually launching it?

Comment: I am calling the launch file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameters set in a launch file are stored at the [ROS parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server).

Accessing these parameters from a python node is quite easy as is shown on [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server). In your case the parameters are defined as *private parameters* of the node (because they are defined inside the `<node>` tag), so you have to prefix them with `~` when accessing them:

```
altitude_max = rospy.get_param('~altitude_max')
```

Comment: For me `rospy.get_param("/ardrone_driver/altitude_max")` worked, but your help was really useful, so thanks.

Comment: just make sure you call before `rospy.init_node("ardrone_driver", anonymous=True)` with the correct node name and you will be able to map private params using rospy.get_param('~altitude_max'), no need to reference the full param path.

Comment: In addition to what @Veilkrand said: When using a launch file, the node name given in `init_node` is irrelevant, instead it uses the `name` set in the `node` tag of the launch file. Therefore it is better to always use `~param_name` when addressing private parameters, as the node itself has no direct control over its name.

Answer (score 1):

For me, rospy.get_param("/ardrone_driver/altitude_max") worked